# Winservice C# and Quartz.net v3.7 - Error "ThreadPool type 'Quartz.Simpl.DefaultThreadPool' props could not be configured"

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net

Good morning,
I am creating a WinService in C# 4.6.2 and I am using Quartz.Net in version 3.7 to set up batch processing on a server.
However, when I start the service I get the following error:

```
Service backup sage - Erreur survenue à '10:25:35' : ThreadPool type 'Quartz.Simpl.DefaultThreadPool' props could not be configured. - StackTrace :    à Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.<Instantiate>d__65.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.<GetScheduler>d__71.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à SupportGriffi.WindowsService.BackupSage.ServiceBackupSage.<OnStart>d__4.MoveNext()
```

I followed the site documentation and used information from this site:
https://mjc.si/2019/08/25/use-quartz-net-library-for-running-tasks-in-a-windows-service/

Here is my code:

Service :

```
        public ServiceBackupSage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            m_ServiceLog = new EventLog();

            string sourceNameService = Properties.Settings.Default.SourceName;
            string logNameService = Properties.Settings.Default.LogName;

            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(sourceNameService))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(sourceNameService, logNameService);
            }
            // configure the event log instance to use this source name
            m_ServiceLog.Source = sourceNameService;
            m_ServiceLog.Log = logNameService;
        }


        protected override async void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                m_ServiceLog.WriteEntry(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Le service backup sage s'est lancé à {0}.", DateTime.Now), EventLogEntryType.Information);

                var properties = new NameValueCollection();

                properties.Add("quartz.scheduler.instanceName", "SchedulerSage");
                properties.Add("quartz.threadPool.type", "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz");
                properties.Add("quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "0");
                //properties.Add("quartz.threadPool.threadPriority", "Normal");
                properties.Add("quartz.threadPool.maxConcurrency", "1");

                m_SchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);

                // get a scheduler
                m_Scheduler = await m_SchedulerFactory.GetScheduler();

                m_ServiceLog.WriteEntry(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "m_SchedulerFactory.GetScheduler OK {0}.", DateTime.Now), EventLogEntryType.Information);

                await m_Scheduler.Start();
                m_ServiceLog.WriteEntry(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Start Scheduler OK {0}.", DateTime.Now), EventLogEntryType.Information);


                //// define the job and tie it to our UserSyncJob class using configurations from app.config as a job data.
                var job = JobBuilder.Create<BackupSageJob>()
                                    .WithIdentity("BackupSageJob", "DefaultGroup")
                                    .UsingJobData("IPServer", Properties.Settings.Default.IPServeur)
                                    .UsingJobData("Login", Properties.Settings.Default.Login)
                                    .UsingJobData("Port", Properties.Settings.Default.Port)
                                    .UsingJobData("Password", Properties.Settings.Default.Password)
                                    .Build();
                m_ServiceLog.WriteEntry(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Création du Job Quartz OK {0}.", DateTime.Now), EventLogEntryType.Information);


                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                        .WithIdentity("BackupSageTrigger", "DefaultGroup")
                        .StartNow()
                        .WithCronSchedule(Properties.Settings.Default.CronSchedule)
                        .Build();
                m_ServiceLog.WriteEntry(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Création du trigger Quartz OK {0}.", DateTime.Now), EventLogEntryType.Information);

                // Tell Quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
                await m_Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
                m_ServiceLog.WriteEntry(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Schedule Job lancé {0}.", DateTime.Now), EventLogEntryType.Information);

                // some sleep to show what's happening
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));




            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                m_ServiceLog.WriteEntry(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Service backup sage - Erreur survenue à '{0}' : {1} - StackTrace : {2}",
                                                DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"),
                                                ex.Message.ToString(),
                                                ex.StackTrace.ToString()), EventLogEntryType.Error);

                throw ex;

            }


        }

        protected override async void OnStop()
        {
            try
            {
                await m_Scheduler.Shutdown();

                // Log d'arrêt du service
                m_ServiceLog.WriteEntry(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                    "Le service backup sage  s'est arreté à '{0}'.",
                    DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")), EventLogEntryType.Information);

                // Fermeture du journal d'évènement
                m_ServiceLog.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

Class IJob :

```
    public class BackupSageJob : IJob
    {
        #region Membres

        /// <summary>
        /// Indique si le traitement est en cours
        /// </summary>
        private static bool m_IsRunning;

        /// <summary>
        /// Journal d'évènement du service
        /// </summary>
        private EventLog m_ServiceLog;

        #endregion Membres       

        public BackupSageJob()
        {
            string sourceNameService = Properties.Settings.Default.SourceName;
            string logNameService = Properties.Settings.Default.LogName;

            // Instanciation du journal d'évènement
            m_ServiceLog = new EventLog(logNameService);
            m_ServiceLog.Source = sourceNameService;
        }


        public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                // Log de démarrage
                m_ServiceLog.WriteEntry(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Lancement de la tache du backup des bases Sage {0}:{1}", DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("00"), 
                                                                                                                                                DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString("00")), 
                                                                                                                                                EventLogEntryType.Information);

                //Load Job configuration
                var key = context.JobDetail.Key;
                var dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;

                var ipftp = dataMap.GetString("IPServer");
                var login = dataMap.GetString("Login");
                var port = dataMap.GetString("Port");
                var password = dataMap.GetString("Password");

                Task taskBackup = new Task(() => BackupSageService.LaunchBackup(ipftp, login, password));

                taskBackup.Start();


                // Log de succès
                m_ServiceLog.WriteEntry(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "Fin de la tache de la tache du backup des bases Sage  {0}:{1}",
                    DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("00"), DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString("00")),
                    EventLogEntryType.Information);

                return taskBackup;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                m_ServiceLog.WriteEntry(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                                    "Erreur de la tache de la tache du backup des bases Sage  {0}:{1}\n{2}",
                                                    DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("00"),
                                                    DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString("00"),
                                                    EventLogEntryType.Error,
                                                    e.Message));

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know what to add in the properties to make this Windows Service work.
Do you have any ideas ?

I thank you in advance

I tried to modify the properties using the answer from this site:
https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/436

and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By searching the Quartz.Net code I found the place that throws the exception

in class : class StdSchedulerFactory : ISchedulerFactory

the method :  private async Task Instantiate()

```
            // Get ThreadPool Properties
        // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

        var threadPoolTypeString = cfg.GetStringProperty(PropertyThreadPoolType).NullSafeTrim();
        if (threadPoolTypeString != null
            && threadPoolTypeString.StartsWith("Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // default to use as synonym for now
            threadPoolTypeString = typeof(DefaultThreadPool).AssemblyQualifiedNameWithoutVersion();
        }

        Type tpType = loadHelper.LoadType(threadPoolTypeString) ?? typeof(DefaultThreadPool);

        try
        {
            tp = InstantiateType<IThreadPool>(tpType);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            initException = new SchedulerException("ThreadPool type '{0}' could not be instantiated.".FormatInvariant(tpType), e);
            throw initException;
        }
        tProps = cfg.GetPropertyGroup(PropertyThreadPoolPrefix, true);
        try
        {
            ObjectUtils.SetObjectProperties(tp, tProps);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            **initException = new SchedulerException("ThreadPool type '{0}' props could not be configured.".FormatInvariant(tpType), e);
            throw initException;**
        }
```

in class: ObjectUtils
the method :

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Sets the object properties using reflection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The object to set values to.</param>
    /// <param name="props">The properties to set to object.</param>
    public static void SetObjectProperties(object obj, NameValueCollection props)
    {
        // remove the type
        props.Remove("type");

        foreach (string name in props.Keys)
        {
            try
            {
                var value = props[name];
                SetPropertyValue(obj, name, value);
            }
            catch (Exception nfe)
            {
                throw new SchedulerConfigException(
                    $"Could not parse property '{name}' into correct data type: {nfe.Message}", nfe);
            }
        }
    }
```

And I keep looking... it's really not easy!